# Databricks Repo vs Workspace

Tags: repository, databricks, azure-databricks, repo, aws-databricks

I noticed that in Databricks, there is a folder section for 'Workspace' and a folder for 'Repos' - as seen below:

[image]

I have been trying to research online what the difference is, but no luck. It seems as though they serve the same purpose? I am able to manage source code in both.

Is there any difference between the two? And are there any best practices for which I should use - especially if I am working with a team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Workspace is generally where you create and work on notebooks of different languages i.e., Python, SQL, Scala or R. You can also add libraries, new folders or an ML flow experiment

[image]

- As you can see, there is a `Users` section where there is the list of users. Once you configured the users, each of the user's resources can be easily managed.
- Refer to this [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workspace/) which has detailed information about Databricks workspace.
- **Repos** are basically used for GIT integration. You can add your repository as shown below:

[image]

- We use Repos whenever we want to work our GIT repositories and all the general GIT operations are supported.
- Refer to this [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos/) to completely understand the capabilities of Databricks repos.
- So, as far as I know, you choose Databricks Repos when your work includes development through GIT. Anything that does not involve GIT integration can be carried out through Databricks Workspace resources itself.

Comment: The devision of repo and workspaces is werid, counterintuitive. I mean in normal case, some directory under the user workspace directory tree can be git repos. But now, they make it separate!

Answer (score 0):

These have now been updated to be part of the same thing:

[image: Screenshot of the new UI]

Although they kinda look like they're still sorta seperate, you can also cross-reference between them if you want to - for example to run a notebook in your repo from your workspace, you would write

```
%run "/Workspace/Repos/your_name@your.domain/repo-name/some-folder-in-the-repo/notebook-name"
```

I haven't tested the other way around (accessing a workspace folder from a repo) but presumably that would work too if you really wanted to - you can get the full path for something by using the ellipses:

[image: screenshot of the copy URL/path context menue for a notebook]